# SlimPHP - strange error with extending twig (function)

Tags: php, twig, slim

I have some simple app in PHP Slim (newest version) , it's a  simple  website that gets data from database and display it on twig  templates. Nothing fancy.
Everything  works  perfect as long as i don't try to add custom function to twig.

When i add custom function to twig, on some servers(on localhost laragoon works fine,on production server with the same php version not i get this error :

**Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Twig_Function in ... twig.php on line 4**

below is my twig.php - error is connected to **new Twig_Function** ,but honestly i don't see any abstract class here ..., and on localhost Laragon it's working fine , on production

Anyone have any idea how to solve this problem ?

```
<?php

$twig=$container->get('view')->getEnvironment();
$function = new Twig_Function('fotki', function ($id) use ($container) {
    $files=array();
    $dir=opendir($container->get('settings')['fotki_path'].(int)$id);
    while($file=readdir($dir)){
        if((strlen($file)>3)&&(substr($file,-3)=='jpg')){
            array_push($files,(int)$id.'/'.$file);
            //
            }
    }
    closedir($dir);
    return $files;


});
$twig->addFunction($function);

$function = new Twig_Function('fotkalink', function ($path) use ($container) {
    $tab=explode('/',$path);
    return 'mediaimage/'.$tab[0].'-'.$tab[1];
});
$twig->addFunction($function);
```

Declaration of  view in container :

```
$container['view'] = function ($c)  {
    $a=[];
    if($c['settings']['env']=='prod')
        $a=[ 'cache' => __DIR__.'/../cache'];
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig( __DIR__.'/../templates', $a);
    $basePath = rtrim(str_ireplace('index.php', '', $c['request']->getUri()->getBasePath()), '/');
    $view->addExtension(new Slim\Views\TwigExtension($c['router'], $basePath));

    return $view;
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make use of the [`Twig_SimpleFunction`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/api/2.x/Twig_SimpleFunction.html) which extends of `Twig_Function` as you can't instantiate an abstract class.

```
$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('fotkalink', function ($path) use ($container) {
    $tab=explode('/',$path);
    return 'mediaimage/'.$tab[0].'-'.$tab[1];
});
$twig->addFunction($function);
```

Comment: ehhh sure - you're 100%  right. I don't know why i didn't saw this :/

Comment: Well, the docs make use of Twig_Function in the examples when you look it up. So I'm really happy this question exists.

Comment: Yeah i don't get why the docs have you use the abstract class. Feelsbadman. Thats why I'm here as well.

Comment: Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?